# Modify Serenity project after removing somedata column from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, cucumber-serenity

I made some changes from SQL Server. I removed some data column from there. After that I try to run serenity project I get some errors about this changes. It can not find this deleted columns.

How can I solve this and update columns in project?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: ı removed 'marketlinks' from  product table and so when  open product page  I get invalid column name 'marketlinks' error

Comment: This needs clarification, how did you make those changes and what are the erros?